# How to select unclosed tag and close it automatically?

Tags: tags, filetype-html

Here is my html file already edited,there are two errors in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="   " />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>6 navs</nav
    <div>intro</div>
    <div>edu</div>
    <div>specialization</div>
    <div>work/div>
    <div>production</div>
    <nav>contact</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

1.not **`<nav>6 navs</nav`** but **`<nav>6 navs</nav>`**
2.not **`<div>work/div>`**   but **`<div>work</div>`**

How to choose the two errors automatically with vim command or some plugins?
How to fix it ,enclosed it automatically after locating the position?

Comment: https://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/ A good plugin for html files though it relies heavily on visual mode.

Comment: Another plugin to suggest would be https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag - it won't fix errors, but will ensure that tags are closed properly (unless you manually break them later on)